# Can I detect IE6 with PHP?

Tags: php, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

Is there a way to use PHP to detect if the page is being loaded using IE6?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: haha lets kill ie6 http://www.bringdownie6.com/

Comment: Because it is old and time consuming to develop for and sometimes you want to just redirect them to a crappy, old version of your site.

Comment: I want to add a message to my site for IE6 users telling them to update their junk already.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try checking their user agent for `'MSIE 6.'`.

```
$using_ie6 = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.') !== FALSE);
```

This is based on [this user agent information](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/).

Comment: This will often match Opera as well, because Opera often adds "MSIE 6.0" within their user-agent string.

Comment: Recent versions of Opera do NOT (by default) have MSIE 6.0 in the user-agent string

Comment: In my case, this is a false positive for all MSIE browser since all of  them list "MSIE 6.0 compatible" even if their version is actually higher.

Comment: @thomasrutter - Just add `&& !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera')` to your `if` condition

Answer (score 28):

You can detect IE6 with HTML this way

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
// ie6 only stuff here
<![endif]-->
```

<s>[Here's a link on how it's done in PHP](http://www.studioyucca.com/2008/10/01/detecting-ie6-in-php/)</s><sup>[Way Back Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20081221042900/http://www.studioyucca.com/2008/10/01/detecting-ie6-in-php/)</sup> but I've seen many false positives in parsing the `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` for IE6

Comment: This may be useful sometimes, but it isn't actually an answer to the question. It asks how to do so with PHP. The user agent might be IE, but it might not be rendering HTML.

Answer (score 15):

Many of the user-agent based answers on this page aren't too reliable because Opera often identifies itself with a user-agent string containing "MSIE 6.0", such as:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; X11; Linux i686; en) Opera 9.51
```

*This affects all versions of Opera 5 through 9 and even Opera 10 and can be turned on or off from within Opera.  [See this page](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera/).*

A common approach I've seen is to test for "MSIE" and against "Opera".  For example,

```
if (preg_match('/\bmsie 6/i', $ua) && !preg_match('/\bopera/i', $ua))
  echo "We have IE6!";
```

Comment: $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if (preg_match('/\bmsie [56]\./i', $ua) && !preg_match('/\b(opera|msie [789])/i', $ua)) {
        echo 'IE 5 or 6';
    }

Comment: strpos() will do the job quicker here.

Answer (score 12):

well PHLAK...

i think this one is much better :P

```
  if(preg_match('/msie [2-6]/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
   // if IE<=6
  } else {
   //if IE>6
  }
```

Comment: Works great, except "preg" should be "preg_match".

Comment: The syntax `'/msie [1-6]/i'` is shorter, and is probably more familiar to most people.

Comment: yep, you right :) but it was 3 years ago and nowadays my regexp skills are more more much better than then ;)

Comment: Note that this method will incorrectly identify IE10 as a match.

Comment: the `//if IE>6` comment is misleading. EVERY other browsers will fail the match.

Comment: That's why it's listed in the else statement, neokio.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [get_browser](http://php.net/get_browser) with [updated browscap.ini file](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp).

Comment: This sounds interesting, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

Like everyone else said, there **will** be false positives by just checking the user agent... so why not use **both**, user agent checking and a conditional comment.

for example...

```
<? if (preg_match('/\bmsie 6/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) { ?>
  <!--[if IE 6]>
    // ie6 only stuff here
  <![endif]-->
<? } ?>
```

This way you won't be sending back this unnecessary code to most browsers... but will still be safe in case of a false positive.

Answer (score 3):

You *can*, using the HTTP User-Agent header, but I'd strongly advise not doing that if possible. The User-Agent header is very very difficult to parse accurately, and tends towards false positives with simple string matching — even ignoring the issue of browsers that pretend to be other browsers. For example Jeremy's “MSIE 6.” string will match IE Mobile, which is so very different from IE6 that you generally don't want to conflate them.

Plus when you send different HTML to different browsers, you have to use the ‘Vary’ header (which makes caches less effective) to avoid that caches send the wrong pages to different browsers.

So if you can find another place to do the browser differentiation that's definitely best. Ólafur's approach with conditional comments is usually the simplest approach for changing JavaScript and HTML markup/CSS links.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it for many browsers, but it is time consuming and sometimes false positive...

```
function do_stylesheet_link() {
// Picks up appropriate css file depending on the user-agent

//  if ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') ) {
//echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/firefox.css" type="text/css" />'; }    

//elseif ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') ) {
//echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chrome.css" type="text/css" />'; }

//elseif ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') ) {
//echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safari.css" type="text/css" />'; }

//elseif ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') ) {
//echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/opera.css" type="text/css" />'; }

    if ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.') )  {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6.css" type="text/css" />'; }

elseif ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 7.') ) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" type="text/css" />'; }

elseif ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 8.') ) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" type="text/css" />'; }

else {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />';
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,34)=="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;")
  echo "I am stupid IE6";`

IE 6 Always starts  with "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;"
IE 7,8 have "MSIE 6" in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I ended up creating the following function and calling it as needed:

```
// IE6 Check
function isIE() {
  $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  if (ereg("msie 6.0", $userAgent)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick tip: use the preg functions in PHP instead of ereg, they're faster. http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Scratch that, you shouldn't be using a regular expression function at all if you're only checking for the existence of a string. Use strpos as the answer above suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The methods listed will often flag browsers with certain plug-ins (MathPlayer, for instance; as well as some malware toolbars).

I find a much more reliable method is:

```
if( preg_match('/^Mozilla\/4\.0 \(compatible; MSIE 6/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) != 0 )
```

Comment: The snippet in the if returns TRUE if IE6 is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Something simpler:

```
if(stristr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "msie 6.0")) {
    // IE6? Aren't you out of fashion yet?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isIE($versions=array()) {
    if (!empty($versions))
        $versions = '('.implode('|',$versions).')';
    else
        $versions = '1?\d';
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $is_not_opera = false===stripos($ua, 'opera');
    return $is_not_opera && preg_match('/\bmsie '.$versions.'\./i', $ua);
}
```

Using:

```
$is_ie = isIE(); //Any version
$is_ie_7 = isIE(array(7)); //IE 7
$is_old_id = isIE(array(6,7));//IE 7 and 8
```

Answer (score 0):

very helpful thread. I used this to hide the `<?xml>` declaration for IE6. Turns out IE6 only checks the first line of the document for doctype sniffing, which means that if the `<?xml>` string is present, IE6 will render in quirks mode regardless of the doctype following the `<?xml>` declaration

I'm not sure if its critical to include an opera check yet, but have included it anyway.

```
//check if IE 6 or less
$not_lte_ie6 = true;
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(strpos($ua,'msie') !== FALSE) {
    if(strpos($ua,'opera') === FALSE) {
        if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-6]/',$ua)) $not_lte_ie6 = false;
    }
}
if ($not_lte_ie6)
    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isOldIE() {
    // don't support IE6 or below
    return preg_match('/MSIE [1-6]/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Function is preg_match() instead of preg(), but good !

Answer (score -1):

Note IE8 also specifies that it is IE6 compatible in its user-agent string.

Comment: I found this out to be true recently when a user contacted me to say they were using IE8 but I detected it as IE6. Their user agent string was this: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)

Comment: I studied this and it seems that it only happens if the IE is in compatibility view.