# browser detection cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, cakephp

How do you detect IE, firefox, chrome in cakephp?
thanks

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5302302/327074. Since there's no specific 'cake' way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about cake php but http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php gives some good info and is a built in php function.

edit: spelling

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is my solution to detect navigator

You can put this code in your routes.php

```
  if(!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 8' ) !== TRUE) { 
router::connect(etc.....);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
 $msie = strpos($userAgent, 'MSIE') ? true : false; // Internet Explorer
 $firefox = strpos($userAgent, 'Firefox') ? true : false; // Firefox
 $safari = strpos($userAgent, 'Safari') ? true : false; // Webkit powered browser
 $chrome = strpos($userAgent, 'Chrome') ? true : false; // Webkit powered browser
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you would like to do.

If it is related to CSS, I would use conditional css files
[Conditional CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

If it is related to pure php, the get browser function will do ok. Here is a script that I found on google that uses it. You could probably use this in your application.
[Browser Class](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/)

If you can wait until the page is loaded, use Javascript. I know Mootools has its own Browser class and I would guess that jQuery does to. Here is the Mootools documentation.
[Mootools Browser Class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Browser/Browser)

This would be my recommended solution.

Have a great day!

Comment: This is mega old, but for people who do not know, conditional comments are no longer supported as of IE10

Comment: I now use the MobileDetect plugin from cake.

Comment: Thankfully, IE 10 actually looks like a standards browser.