# Detect Internet Explorer from PHP (version 11 too)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser-detection

What is the correct way to detect Internet Explorer in PHP, any version, including IE 11?

Tried:

```
f(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident') !== false || 
   strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))){
```

The above does not work for me.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18070424/ (if you haven't already) see if that helps. There is some info about Trident in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: If internet explorer 6, 7, 8 , or 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9)

Answer (score 0):

I found the get_browser_properties function on http://buffernow.com/get-browser-properties-without-browscap-in-php/ works for me