# Site not working correctly in IE how can i replace content with banner or alert users?

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

[mysite](http://redsparr0w.com/3d-skins.php?skinid=198#modelbox) is not displaying the 3D content very well at all compared to chrome in IE is there any way that i can replace the content with a banner letting the user know "you will not have as good an experience using IE and using Chrome or other supported browsers will make it better" or an alert notifying the same thing?

answer using php or html or jquery please.

Thanks.

*note: i have tried the following code to no success as it still doesnt detect im using IE unless IE is using compatibility view (which destroys the site completely)*

> if (eregi("MSIE",getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT")) ||
>          eregi("Internet Explorer",getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))) {
>       echo ("Sorry Internet Explorer currently cannot handle the 3d views on this website correctly, \nPlease use Chrome to get the full effect");
>       die();
>      }

Comment: You could use JS, PHP, or HTML, for this. Have you looked at some of the solutions that already address this? Is there a minimum version of IE you want to target the message at?

Comment: All versions of IE seem to not work properly. it still shows a 3d view of the model but terrible quality and only 360 degree horizontal rotation. all the codes i have tried only detect IE in compatibility mode for some reason

Comment: please don't use the `ereg` family of functions. Use `preg` instead. `DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0`

Comment: changed it to preg_match now it doesnt seem to work at all in detecting IE

Comment: This has been done before please look at previously defined methods and if you have issues with them post on that. 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-prior-to-v9-in-javascript 3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx 4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 does not have the "MSIE" string in the user agent. It does have the Trident/ string (as does every IE version since 8), so you could look for that.