# How can I restrict IE users to view my site?

Tags: php

My website looks awful in Internet Explorer, but I have no problems with Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, etc.

Is there a possibility to restrict access to my website for IE users?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: If internet explorer 6, 7, 8 , or 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9)

Comment: ok... thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is rather css question. You can add something like this in you HTML:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <style>
        body {
            display:none !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

which will hide your whole body for IE later or equal then 8.

But maybe better way will be to hide content and show some info to atualize your browser instead.