# conditional inside td tag to perform php scripts

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to perform two different scripts depending on if its IE11 or not

Consider the following pseudo code

```
<td>
  if IE11 
    perform  IE11_Code
  else
    perform  other_code
  end if
</td>
```

How can I archive this.

Detecting IE11 apparently works like this.

```
var isAtLeastIE11 = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/));
```

But to use this in the conditional baffles me.

EDIT: forget about the fact that I want to use php in there somewhere.

Comment: PHP runs on server, Javascript on the browser, they can not run at the same time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9

Comment: yeah, I get that. its in the creation phase. It all works fine, but for each browser I need to execute a different line, thats all.

Comment: So you have to detect it on the server or you have to detect it on the client, than make an Ajax call to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the browser on the server side using the HTTP-Header `User-Agent`, which is basically the same as the one used on the client-side when using navigator.userAgent in JavaScript.

I'm not a php expert, but it should work somehow like this:

```
<?php
  $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  if(preg_match('/Trident/', $userAgent) ) {
    ...
  }
?>
```

Comment: "Conditional Comments only work in Internet Explorer on the client side" — They don't work in IE11 and the question doesn't mention them.

Comment: @Quentin you're right, i was somehow reminded of conditional comments because of the word "conditional" and the the peusdo code :)

Comment: Did not know you could get the user browser from php, Thanks mate.