# IE - specific message

Tags: php

I use SVG Charts on my website. It works in all browsers except IE. I would like to add a snippet of PHP code with a message for IE users.

I think I can get the agent info with PHP, but I'm not sure how to detect version. I believe IE 9 supports it now, so I need only for versions below IE 9.

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671890/can-i-detect-ie6-with-php) can be useful for you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PHP for this.

Instead, use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh, that's cool, but they all seem browser specific if IE 7, if IE 6 etc. Can it be do for all IEs under 9?

Comment: Oh, that's what lt is for... Dah... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PHP function `get_browser`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

The site contains numerous examples of how to detect the browser and display an appropriate message.

Answer (score 0):

Put this around the html

```
<![if lt IE 9]> 
    Show stuff to browsers => IE 9
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    hide stuff from browsers < IE 9
<![endif]-->
```