# Not rendering a PHP page to IE

Tags: php, browser

I have a PHP page which breaks down in IE 6 and 7, hence I want users to not use IE. Warnings and notices will be definitely ignored by them. So as a solution, can I just stop rendering the page if the request come from IE  and just display a line that IE is not supported?

I am new to php and hence the question. IE SUCKS!

Comment: It's not problem with php and ie - its problem with html and ie, because php - only generated html text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745412/ie-specific-message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use user-agent checking:

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.0')) {
    echo 'IE6'
};

if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 7.0')) {
    echo 'IE7';
};
```

Comment: Do you mean service packs? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the HTTP user agent request parameter with: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].

```
$usingIE6 = (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6.' ) !== FALSE);

if ($usingIE6) {
  echo 'Please upgrade your browser'; 
  exit;
}
```

Usage statistics are here, IE 6 has a 7% market share:
http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
   (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
```

Its only a snippet and i know that the IE is not the best browser but a good programmer should look at all browsers and make it in all of them correct... this is the actual difficulty in web development.

Comment: I agree... IE 8 and onwards is good enough... but IE 6 and 7 are hell with CSS and JavaScript... hence I wanted to disable IE 6 and 7.

Comment: I partially agree. "A good programmer look at all browsers make it correct this is the difficulty on the web": sure but without IE that's the browser made with foot! If the bug are in the browser, why the programmator must fix them?? Microsoft MUST fix them! If all web-developers stop fixing IE's bugs, you'll see a better new version of IE.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a test on the HTTP_USER_AGENT from the superglobal $_SERVER;

but just to give another option( that might not be what you need, as it fetches way more info and it needs an extra file) you could use [get_browser](http://php.net/get_browser) that relies on [browscap](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp) this is more in case you will sometime need other extra details about the visitor

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called [get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) that will return all the version information you need.

You could also use conditional comments that IE will be able to decipher:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>Your browser is too old for this app. Please upgrade.<![endif]-->
```