# Check if browser IE8 or less using PHP

Tags: php

How to check whether the browser is IE8 or less using php?

Comment: I tried $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  and it was giving me "mozilla" when i chekc it on IE. Thats the reason I posted this question. Sorry, forgot to mention it .

Comment: I up voted this question because it is exactly what I need too.  What have I tried? Well of course the first thing I tried was stackoverflow :).  The answers so far do not address the question. How to detect, in PHP, if the browers is IE8 or less.     I need this in Php so that I can adjust a Drupal theme to not generate some content on the most painful browser in history.   Further search and found this question in SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671890/can-i-detect-ie6-with-php  that also refers to http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/

Comment: See SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671890/can-i-detect-ie6-with-php

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var bro=$.browser; 
    var binfo=""; 
    if(bro.msie) {binfo="Microsoft Internet Explorer "+bro.version;} 
    if(bro.mozilla) {binfo="Mozilla Firefox "+bro.version;} 
    if(bro.safari) {binfo="Apple Safari "+bro.version;} 
    if(bro.opera) {binfo="Opera "+bro.version;} 
    alert(binfo); 
    $("#browser").html(binfo); 
})
```

Comment: How this could be an answer if the question contains PHP tag

Comment: Not only does this not include any php, but it also requires jquery. This is a good answer, but not for this question.

Answer (score 9):

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [2-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

```
<?php
//echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($browser['version']);
?>
```

[image: Check ScreenShot]

Comment: The raw UA is .. well, let's just say there are many values it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/).

Typical usage.

```
$browser = new Browser();
if( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_FIREFOX && $browser->getVersion() >= 2 ) {
    echo 'You have FireFox version 2 or greater';
}
```